# Changing username still leaves old traces

Tags: bash, arch-linux, users, home

I changed my username about a month ago, and although I have forgotten the specificities of how I had done so, I'm pretty sure I followed the instructions on the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/change_username). Since then, some programs, such as `gnome-boxes`, have been mistakenly identifying me by my old username - `zheoffec`:

```
[marcoms@baguette16 Downloads]$ gnome-boxes 

(gnome-boxes:10440): Boxes-WARNING **: libvirt-broker.vala:86: Failed to start storage pool: cannot open path '/home/zheoffec/.local/share/gnome-boxes/images': No such file or directory
```

Of course, my new `$HOME` is `/home/marcoms/`, and running `grep -i zheoffec * --recursive` as root from the root directory only returns strings from `.bash_history` and `fish_history` (`fish` is another shell).

How can I remove all traces of my old username?

Comment: Look at the dot files for traces. e.g... `${HOME}/.gnome`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing usernames afterwards like this can be problematic since the username is often times hard coded into files throughout your $HOME directory.

I usually create a new account with the new name and then migrate files from the old file to the new, but you can also identify them like so:

```
$ grep -r zheoffec $HOME
```

#### Example

```
$ grep -r saml /home/saml
/home/saml/scripts/r.rb:#!/home/saml/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
Binary file /home/saml/parking_lot/db/db1080p.zip matches
Binary file /home/saml/Dropbox/personal/Dropbox/pidgin.tar matches
/home/saml/Dropbox/personal/.viminfo:'0  2  5  /home/saml/bin/dropbox.sh
/home/saml/Dropbox/personal/.viminfo:-'  2  5  /home/saml/bin/dropbox.sh
/home/saml/Dropbox/personal/.viminfo:-'  1  0  /home/saml/bin/dropbox.sh
/home/saml/Dropbox/personal/.viminfo:> /home/saml/bin/dropbox.sh
```

If you decide to create a new account and then copy key pieces of data from the old I'd also recommend using `rsync` to copy files from the old account to the new one as needed. This allows you to copy the data as you go and build up a script that includes key directories of files.

Additionally I'll often copy the dot files `.*` to a subdirectory in the new location called `dotfiles` and once I'm in the new account will use `rsync` to copy subdirectories from `dotfiles` as needed.

Comment: it turns out it was a config file in ~/.config/gtk-3.0, but why didn't `grep --recursive` find it from `/`?

Comment: @marcoms - I'd have to see the file to see if there was anything unique about it.

Answer (score 4):

As @suspectus says, look in dot files:

```
find . -type f -name '.*' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H zheoffec
```